# In .Net how to build filter URL set using elasticsearch?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elasticsearch, nest

I know this could be done by using aggregates. But I can't understand how to render the filter urls(drill down urls) to the view. So that user user can move to the down layer. Should I create them manually or does elasticsearch have built in method to achieve this?

The real problem is this. Say I click link in my category facet and now the URL of the current page looks like: http://example.com/search/cars-for-sale

Once I moved my mouse pointer over the link in location facet url should change like http://example.com/search/cars-for-sale-in-new-york

So my real concern is how to generate urls in the facets related to the current URl ?

[image: In the attached image sub categories are drill down urls]

Comment: Manually - ES does search, not HTML generation.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is there any best way to do this? I'm thinking to create view model for the facets and the result set at the same time and then generate the view.

Comment: Just create a view model that has the most convenient structure for your view - then you can map from your ES results

Comment: I've edited the post. Can you please look in to that.

Comment: Make the facet value a controller action parameter (along with any other criteria) and generate a URL for each facet - I think you need to look up some basic MVC tutorials.